# regex - how to capture two patterns in one group?

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to capture two different patterns into a single capture/match group. Is this even possible?

First pattern: two character alpha-numeric surrounded by spaces `([A-Z0-9]{2})`

Second pattern: two character alpha-numeric preceded by alpha-numeric and a decimal value followed by a space `\b[A-Z ]*\d+\.\d{2}([A-Z0-9]{2})`

These two patterns together capture everything I want but the problem is I need them to be in single capture group and in the order captured (see expected output).

test strings

```
ABC WS PIT342.55USD342.55END
ABC WS YMQ234.03WS TOY234.03USD468.06END
FUR BB LAB Q10.00 199.00USD209.00END
YAS DG TYY Q AWSMSN11.32 2503.08LD VET Q JKLOLE11.32 2503.08USD5028.80END
PPP VP LAP Q10.00 M342.41EE SFD Q10.00 282.24USD644.65END
YAS DL X/XXX MO X/POP DF PSC241.30ET X/SAE DL X/KOO DL CSG269.80USD511.10END
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2v2S8G/2)

expected output

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| ABC WS PIT342.55USD342.55END                                                 | WS                     |
| ABC WS YMQ234.03WS TOY234.03USD468.06END                                     | WS, WS                 |
| FUR BB LAB Q10.00 199.00USD209.00END                                         | BB                     |
| YAS DG TYY Q AWSMSN11.32 2503.08LD VET Q JKLOLE11.32 2503.08USD5028.80END    | DG, LD                 |
| PPP VP LAP Q10.00 M342.41EE SFD Q10.00 282.24USD644.65END                    | VP, EE                 |
| YAS DL X/XXX MO X/POP DF PSC241.30ET X/SAE DL X/KOO DL CSG269.80USD511.10END | DL, MO, DF, ET, DL, DL |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Would `(?:\b[A-Z ]*\d+\.\d{2}([A-Z0-9]{2}))?([A-Z0-9]{2})` work?

Comment: You can make spaces on the ends of your regex more distinct by escaping them or enclosing them in a character class (`[ ]`).

Comment: I am not sure about bringing both patterns in one group but if you want the expected output then you can also get it using 2 groups. (?:\b\w+?\.\d{2})([A-Z]{2}\b)|(\b[A-Z]{2}\b)

Comment: I tested this in the link you gave and I can see both patterns in one Group. Try this out - (?:\b\w+?\.\d{2})?[^A-Z]([A-Z]{2}\b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could omit the space from the character class `[A-Z ]*` as it would not match the first `WS` in this part `WS YMQ234.03WS` for example.

As both patterns have the same part at then end with the 2 alphanumerics and the space, you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` to match either the preceding space or the first part of the second pattern.

```
(?:\b[A-Z]*\d+\.\d{2}| )([A-Z0-9]{2})
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation `|`

  - `\b[A-Z]*\d+\.\d{2}` Word boundary, match 0+ times a char A-Z, 1+ digits, dot and 2 digits
  - `|` Or
      Match a space
- `)` Close non capture group
- `([A-Z0-9]{2})` Capture **group 1**, match 2 times an alphanumeric

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dL6E7l/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/W5zCqE)

Example code

```
import re

strings = [
    "ABC WS PIT342.55USD342.55END",
    "ABC WS YMQ234.03WS TOY234.03USD468.06END",
    "FUR BB LAB Q10.00 199.00USD209.00END",
    "YAS DG TYY Q AWSMSN11.32 2503.08LD VET Q JKLOLE11.32 2503.08USD5028.80END",
    "PPP VP LAP Q10.00 M342.41EE SFD Q10.00 282.24USD644.65END",
    "YAS DL X/XXX MO X/POP DF PSC241.30ET X/SAE DL X/KOO DL CSG269.80USD511.10END"
]

for s in strings: 
    print(re.findall(r"(?:\b[A-Z]*\d+\.\d{2}| )([A-Z0-9]{2}) ", s))
```

Output

```
['WS']
['WS', 'WS']
['BB']
['DG', 'LD']
['VP', 'EE']
['DL', 'MO', 'DF', 'ET', 'DL', 'DL']
```

Comment: What does `?:` do?

Comment: @nobody It is a non capturing group for the alternation `|` I will add an explanation.